# Collection View "cellForItemAt" Index out of range

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am getting index out of range fatal error. I am trying to implement 2 collection views in one cell of a Table View controller. Both have different data sources. While loading image data in the cell from data source, the 2nd collection view cell isnt loaded with image data due to this error.
Even when I dumped the contents of `BList` , it has 5 objects in (key,value) pair fashion
The error is occuring at follwing line

`let bannerList = BList[indexPath.row]`

I have looked upon other similar questions but none of them was useful

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! T_PCollectionViewCell

    if (collectionView === upperBannerCollectionView) {
        if OList.count > 0 {
            let olist2 = OList[indexPath.row]
            cell.load_image(olist2.banner_image)
        }
    } else {
        if BList.count > 0 {
            let blist = BList[indexPath.row]
            cell.load_image(blist.banner_image)
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

Here is the implementation for `numberOfItems' for collectionView

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        if (collectionView === uBCollectionView) {
            return self.OList.count
        } else {
            return self.BList.count
        }
    }
```

Added the debug of print(BList) with image

[debug of print(BList)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYSlk.png)
[debugger screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITBiq.png)

I should not get such index out of range error while trying to load the data from data sources BannerList.

Comment: You should be calling `bannerList.count` and `bannerList[indexPath.row]`. `bannerList` and `otokuList` instead of `BannerList` and `OtokuList`.

Comment: show your `numberOfItems` implementation

Comment: The `.count > 0` checks are pointless. `cellForItemAt` doesn't get called at all if the data source array is empty. I guess you are trying to use **two** data source arrays simultaneously which cannot work. Add the data source array and `numberOfItems`.

Comment: can you print the count of arrays just before the line that breaks and post it here ?

Comment: @MilanNosáľ updated question with `numberOfItems` implementation.

Comment: @humblePilgrim posted the debug screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I think that you main problem is the array in you "numberOfItemsInSection".

lets suppose that you're using **OtokuList.count** in "**numberOfItemsInSection**"
and OtokuList has 3 items in that moment but BannerList has just one item.

```
 if BannerList.count > 0 { //this validation will work even if indexPath.row is 2
       let bannerList = BannerList[indexPath.row] //this line will crash
       cell.load_image(bannerList.banner_image)
  }
```

My solution for this is:

```
if BannerList.count > indexPath.row {
      let bannerList = BannerList[indexPath.row]
      cell.load_image(bannerList.banner_image)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue accure when collectionView not able to find the index. To resolve this issue we need to apply small check. yourArray.count > indexPath.row.

```
 if cellData.viewModel.serviceCategoriesArray.count > indexPath.row {
        
        cellData.viewModel.selectedCategory = cellData.viewModel.serviceCategoriesArray[indexPath.row]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. In my case it occurred because data was being reloaded in the viewDidLoad. When I changed the reload to viewWillAppear, the collection view started with the correct indexPath.row.